# Facebook sharing link error

Tags: facebook, http, facebook-apps, facebook-sharer

I'm using this working example to create a share link:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=145634995501895&display=popup&caption=An%20example%20caption&link=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fdialogs%2F&redirect_uri=https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

I change app_id to one which I created, and links which are placed in app settings too.

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=755901181123275&display=popup&caption=An%20example%20caption&link=http://www.tousdanette.com/&redirect_uri=http://www.tousdanette.com/

It is working if i'm logged in with account which I used to create the app. But if I send link to another person it shows an error:

> "An error occurred. Please try again later."

Maybe I need to apply some settings in fb app? or any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue a while back,

Go to your [application dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com) and the app that uses the ID you require and see if the application is live to the public.

If this doesnt work try a diffrent app to test the link.